# Evaluate the integral if possible

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

> Evaluate the following integral, if possible: $$\int_1^4
>  \frac{w}{w-3}dw$$

$$u= w-3,\; du = dw$$
$$\int_1^4 \frac{u+3}{u}du \Rightarrow \int_1^4 \frac{u}{u}du + \int_1^4 \frac{3}{u}du$$
$$\Rightarrow w-3 \bigg|^4_1 + 3\ln w-3\bigg|^4_1 \Rightarrow 3 + 3\ln -2 + c$$

Did I do this correctly?

Edit:  Just realized I did it wrong.
There is a asymptote at w = 3 so I now have it set up like the following:

$$\int_1^4\frac{w}{w-3}dw \rightarrow \int_1^3 \frac{w}{w-3}dw + \int_3^4\frac{w}{w-3}dw$$
$$\int_1^3 \frac{w}{w-3}dw\; \Rightarrow \;^\lim_{t\rightarrow 3^-} \int^t_1 \frac{w}{w-3}\; \Rightarrow \;^\lim_{t\rightarrow 3^-} \int^{t-3}_{-2} \frac{w}{w-3} $$
$$^\lim_{t\rightarrow 3^-} \int^{t-3}_{-2} du + ^\lim_{t\rightarrow 3^-} \int^{t-3}_{-2}\frac1udu$$
$$^\lim_{t\rightarrow 3^-}t-1+3ln(t-3)-3ln(2)$$

is this looking right?

Edit2: Through calculators I have found that 
$$^\lim_{t\rightarrow 3^-}t-1+3ln(t-3)-3ln(2) = -\infty$$
If this is the case, the integral is divergent rendering it impossible to integrate.

Can anyone confirm that this is correct?

Comment: you need to change the upper and lower limits.. i.e while substituing $u=w-3$, the upper limit becomes $1$ whereas the lower becomes $-2$

Comment: Be careful: there is a singularity of your function in the interval you're integrating over, in which case the fundamental theorem of calculus will not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the substitutions; it's good to set $u=w-3$, but with this the integral becomes
$$
\int_1^4\frac{w}{w-3}\,dw=
\int_{-2}^1\frac{u+3}{u}\,du=
\int_{-2}^1du+\int_{-2}^1\frac{1}{u}\,du
$$
Now we see the problem more clearly: the function $f(u)=1/u$ is not defined in $0$, which is inside the interval over which we integrate. Thus we must interpret this as an improper (or generalized) integral and existence of $\int_{-2}{1}(1/u)\,du$ is equivalent to the (existence and) finiteness of both
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}\int_{-2}^x\frac{1}{u}\,du
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_{x}^1\frac{1}{u}\,du
$$
Neither is finite: for instance
$$
\int_x^1\frac{1}{u}\,du=\log1-\log x\xrightarrow{x\to0^+}\infty
$$

Note that an incorrect result would be obtained if one doesn't take care of the singularity: arguing like
$$
\int_{-2}^1du+\int_{-2}^1\frac{1}{u}\,du=[u]_{-2}^1+[\log|u|]_{-2}^1=
1+2+\log 1-\log|{-2}|=3-\log2
$$
would be utterly wrong.